# Do clothing abilities that affect pins only affect the character wearing it?

Tags: neo-the-world-ends-with-you

Some clothing items have abilities that affect pin strength. For example, the Strapped Pumps have Gusty Synergy, which "Increases the power of Wind affinity pins."

If I equip an item with Gusty Synergy, does it increase the power of every party member's Wind affinity pin? Or does it only affect the pin equipped to the character wearing the item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, these abilities are per-character.

While looking at your Threads or Pins, there is a button you can press <kbd>-</kbd> (Switch) or <kbd>Options</kbd> (PS4) to see what abilities are active, and which characters they affect (or if they affect the entire party)